# what is the hotkey to change noise distortion types in the displace modifier?

Tags: workflow

Is there a way to quickly toggle between the different types of noise distortions and Basis' ?

Id like a faster way to switch between them, ideally scrolling through each one for 1s, to see result of modifier. Like a 'next' key for the selection list.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold Ctrl + Scrolling over the button will do what you want.